# Get current input value in function that is set as variable within another function. (I AM STUMPED) code examples within

Tags: javascript, function, events

I have a difficult question, I am trying to get the input value of an input field, however, I need this to happen within another function.

I already have code that works outside of this other function but I need to refactor it to work inside another function that I am calling.

Examples of working code and non-working code are below.

---

Here is the HTML where I am getting the input:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {
    var config = {
      baseUrl: "js",
    };

    var dependencies = ["otherFile"];

    require(config, dependencies);
  })();
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
  <label>Input URL</label>
  <input type="url" />
  <p id="targetInput"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the non-working JS that I am trying to call within another function:

```
function someOtherFunction() {
  var getCurrentInput = function() { };
  var input = document.querySelector("input");
  var log = document.getElementById("targetInput");

  input.addEventListener("input", getCurrentInput);

  var getCurrentInput = function (e) {
  log.currentInput = e.target.value;
  };
  }
  });
```

Lastly here is the working code that works outside of the scope of someOtherFunction

```
  var getCurrentInput = "";
  var input = document.querySelector("input");
  var log = document.getElementById("targetInput");

  input.addEventListener("input", getCurrentInput);

  function getCurrentInput(e) {
  log.currentInput = e.target.value;
  }
```

Now you may notice that there isn't a form being submitted here, the reason for this is because this code is running on an iframe that is being called into another app. The submit is happening there but requires me to call a function to make it happen and technically isn't a submit, meaning I don't have control over it like a regular submit. This is why I need to call the current input value inside someOtherFunction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated here! Essentially I want to get the value inside the input and update my API with the value as a JSON string. There must be a better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a bit difficult to follow at first given the nesting, but something like this?

```js
const doThing = (e) => {
  let input = document.getElementById("input");
  let log = document.getElementById("targetInput");
  log.textContent = input.value; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Input URL</label>
  <input type="url" id="input"/>
  <p id="targetInput"> </p>
</div>

<button onclick="doThing()">Click</button>
```

Essentially an external submit that takes an internal input value, and injects it into another internal element?

Comment: Sorry was late so I will reformat in the morning. - Thank you for attempting. The issue is that I have limited control over the button. It will not accept an onclick, the button is behind another app and can only accept a few parameters that are specific to the CRM. In this case, the button will save the end result of the input as a JSON string. What I can do is create functions that will handle data before the final result is saved. Sorry if that's confusing.

Comment: Since my problem was very abstract your solution, in essence, was exactly what I was trying to achieve. This is the best answer and I appreciate your input (pun intended). I went with a very similar solution and wish I could share the exact code here but it's behind NDA. Thank you for your efforts!